# Variable String no soporta un imagen in base64

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, base64

Buenos días tengo una librería, que me genera una imagen `base64` desde mi **JSP**, esa imagen la envio *servlet* mediante un *post*, cuando lo recibo no recibo la información de caracteres completa , acaso el `string` no soporta la cadena en `base64`.

Funcion desde el jsp con el javascript:

```
function proceso(){
     var socio  = document.getElementById('socio').value;
     var foto64  = document.getElementById('foto64').value;
     f.action='/APLICACIONES/CL_T_FirmaFoto_Servlet?persona='+socio+'&foto64='+foto64;
     f.submit();
}
```

Recepción en el servlet:

```
Date fec = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String strCodUsu = session.getAttribute("strCodUsu")== null ? "" : (String)session.getAttribute("strCodUsu");
String strCodFoto = request.getParameter("foto64")!=null?(String)request.getParameter("foto64"):"";
String  strCodigoCliente = request.getParameter("persona")!=null?request.getParameter("persona"):"";
```

El sistema tiene **java 6**, acaso no soporta esa cadena de base64, acabo de leer que el string soporta hasta 2gb

[image: aca la imagen]

Aca envio la cadena de imagen en base64 y la cantidad que llega en mi string , espero lo puedan apreciar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca la cantidad de caracteres que llegar a mi **servlet**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es el tamaño del mensaje post incluyendo el base64 de la imagen? A la instancia String no le interesa el contenido que le pongas; más bien explica por qué dices que no llega completa

Comment: Envio esa cantidad  en mi variable de javascript , esa es la cantidad de caracteres y en servlet llega esa poca cantidad, es la primera vez que veo este tipo caso, acabo de poner las dos imagenes espero lo puedas ver.

Comment: Intenta escribir la imagen. Transforma ese b64 en un File y mira si escribe la imagen. Puede ser que el depurador te trunque hasta cierta cantidad de caracteres.

Comment: Esa era mi primera opcion convertilo en blob y luego poner en un file, pero manejo IE8 y algunas opciones no me permite y como es eso que el depurador me trunque cierta cantidad de caracteres por que motivo se da eso.

Comment: estas seguro que estas usando POST en lugar de GET? ten en cuenta que no todos los caracteres se intepretan correctamente en una URL, asegurate de pasar la representacion base64 de la imagen por POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependiendo del servidor y su configuración, la longitud máxima admitida de la URL puede variar. En Tomcat ese valor suele estar alrededor de los 8000 caracteres, así que una imagen que ocupe más de 8KB no se puede mandar como un parámetro en la URL.

En cualquier caso, si estás haciendo un POST, lo lógico y habitual es usar el cuerpo de la petición para mandar la información.

Answer (score 0):

"estas seguro que estas usando POST en lugar de GET? ten en cuenta que no todos los caracteres se intepretan correctamente en una URL, asegurate de pasar la representacion base64 de la imagen por POST "
Don Klaimmore , revise y mi codigo y lo envie la imagen por post correctamente gracias por la ayuda recién soy estudiante.